# How to return two-dimensional arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to implement a Matrix4x4 class for my port of 3D Engine that I had made earlier. Here is what I have so far in my header file:

```
#ifndef MAT4_H
#define MAT4_H

class Matrix4
{

public:
   Matrix4() {}
   float[4][4] getMatrix() { return m; }
   //...
   //other matrix related methods are omitted
   //...
private:
   float m[4][4]; 

};

#endif
```

But the method that is supposed to return the two-dimensional array causes this error:

```
src/Matrix4.h:13:10: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
    float[4][4] getMatrix() { return m; }
         ^
```

I am sorry if this question already has an answer, but the answers that I found on this site were usually about returning pointers instead of an array. Hope you can help, thanks.

Comment: return `vector<vector<float> >` instead?

Comment: @taocp That is quite different to a 2D array. Presumable some code needs the data to be a contiguous block.

Comment: You can return `float[][]`. But vector may be really beter solution.

Comment: @taocp yes, that could fix my problem, but isn't there a way to do this with arrays?

Comment: @PetrPervukhin I had tried `float[][]` before, didn't seem to work either

Comment: @MertcanEkiz Do you *really* need to return the data? Arrays are not copyable or assignable, so you can't actually return one.

Comment: @juanchopanza What if I have to access it from another class? Should i make the array public?

Comment: The question is, do you really need to access the array from another class *as a 2D array*, or is it enough to give access to the array elements?

Comment: @MertcanEkiz - You also need to answer whether you want a copy of the array, or the array itself.  If you look closely at your (failed) attempt, it suggest a copy of the matrix is returned (you didn't return a pointer or a reference).

Comment: I guess accessing elements is enough for my implementation. I had done it this way in the Java version, but I don't remember if it was necessary. Thanks

Comment: @MertcanEkiz - `I had done it this way in the Java version`  C++ isn't Java.  Don't use Java as a guide in writing C++ code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie just a copy was enough, since I had other methods to modify the array

Comment: Yes I am becoming quite familiar with the differences between C++ and Java as I am writing more in C++. But I don't think this was a matter of C++ vs Java code because I knew what I wanted to do (return a copy of the array) and I knew that it is different from returning a reference or a pointer. But thanks, I won't rely on my past Java experiences as much anymore.

Comment: @MertcanEkiz it should be noted that making the getter return by value actually copies the 64 bytes. So depending on how you use it you might want to make it a const ref getter.

Comment: I personally wouldn't provide such a function at all. That's against the data hiding principle. Better return a 1D array from functions `row(int)` and `column(int)` as well as `operator[]` (to support `[i][j]` on a `Matrix4` object; but here you need to decide if you want to have a row or column major interface, i.e. if `operator[]` equals `row` or `column`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest to use `std::array`. But using it directly in code, as multi array, is a bit ugly. So I'd suggest an alias, defined as:

```
#include <array> 

namespace details 
{    
   template<typename T, std::size_t D, std::size_t ... Ds> 
   struct make_multi_array 
    : make_multi_array<typename make_multi_array<T,Ds...>::type, D> {}; 

   template<typename T, std::size_t D>
   struct make_multi_array<T,D> { using type = std::array<T, D>;  };
}

template<typename T, std::size_t D, std::size_t  ... Ds> 
using multi_array = typename details::make_multi_array<T,D,Ds...>::type;
```

Then use it as:

```
public:

   multi_array<float,4,4> getMatrix() { return m; }

private:
   multi_array<float,4,4> m;
```

---

You could use the alias in other places as well, such as:

```
 //same as std::array<int,10> 
 //similar to int x[10] 
 multi_array<int,10>   x;   

 //same as std::array<std::array<int,20>,10>
 //similar to int y[10][20] 
 multi_array<int,10,20> y;   

 //same as std::array<std::array<std::array<int,30>,20>,10>
 //similar to int z[10][20][30]
 multi_array<int,10,20,30> z;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do I access or modify the elements of `multi_array`? I'm sorry, I don't know much about templates

Comment: Just like you access/modify normal arrays (C-arrays), e.g `m[i][j] = 10.5`.

Comment: Alternatively, a `vector` of `multi_array`.

Comment: Note that there's a small catch: an `std::array` of `std::array` is not guaranteed to have all the sub-elements stored contiguously. There could be data interspersed between them (although I don't know if an implementation that actually does that.)

Comment: Just one more quick question to double check: I put the definition of the alias in the global scope right?

Comment: @MertcanEkiz: Just experiment.. and more experiments. You'll figure out lots of things yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an array in either C or C++ is possible by a passing pointer to its first element- the pointer is passed by value.

The only way to pass your array by value would be to encapsulate it
in a struct, but in most cases its better to pass a pointer then to copy all the data by value.

Answer (score -1):

Just return a pointer to the first element of the array! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for your contribution. But, adding some code to your answer would make it much better.